# Efficiently computable function as a counter-example to Sarnak's Mobius conjecture

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, randomness, open-problem, nt.number-theory

Recently, [Gil Kalai](http://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/the-ac0-prime-number-conjecture/) and [Dick Lipton](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/the-depth-of-the-mobius-function/) both wrote nice articles on an interesting conjecture proposed by Peter Sarnak, an expert in number theory and the Riemann Hypothesis.

> **Conjecture.** Let $\mu(k)$ be the [Möbius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function). Suppose $f: \mathbb{N} \to \{-1,1\}$ is an $\mathsf{AC}^0$ function with input $k$ in the form of binary representation of $k$, then
>   $$ \sum_{k \leq n} \mu(k) \cdot f(k) = o(n) \text.$$

Note that if $f(k) = 1$ then we have an equivalent form of the [Prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

**UPDATE**: Ben Green on MathOverflow [provided a short paper](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57543/walsh-fourier-transform-of-the-mobius-function/58081#58081) which claims to prove the conjecture. [Take a look at the paper](http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~bjg23/papers/primes-boolean.pdf).

On the other hand, we know that by setting $f(k) = \mu(k)$ (with slight modification so the range is in $\\{-1,1\\}$), the resulting sum has the estimation
$$ \sum_{k \leq n} \mu(k)^2 = \Omega(n) \text.$$
There is an upper bound that $\mu(k)$ can be computed in $\mathsf{UP} \cap \mathsf{coUP} \subseteq \mathsf{NP} \cap \mathsf{coNP}$, so the constraint proposed on $f(k)$ in the conjecture cannot be relaxed to an $\mathsf{NP}$ function.
My question is:

> What is the lowest complexity class $\mathsf{C}$ we currently know, such that a function $f(k)$ in $\mathsf{C}$ satisfies the estimation
>   $$ \sum_{k \leq n} \mu(k) \cdot f(k) = \Omega(n) \text{?}$$
>   In particular, since some of the theorists believe that computing $\mu(k)$ is not in $\mathsf{P}$, can we provide other $\mathsf{P}$ functions $f(k)$ which implies a linear growth in the summation? Can even better bounds be obtained?

Comment: Some quantum class like P^{BQNC} should also work, since factoring lies in that class.

Comment: Is this even known if $f(k) = k_i$ for a fixed $i$?

Comment: @Emanuele, good question. The indicator function of the i-th bit in the binary representation of k is a linear "bracket polynomial", but it has very high coefficients, so it might not follow from the Green-Tao theorem on the correlation of the Mobius function with bounded-step nilsequences. Bounded-step nilsequences have bounded-degree bracket polynomials as special cases, but their result might have some restrictions on the magnitudes of the coefficients

Comment: And is it known for $f \in NC^0$?

Comment: Do you want a function $f$ with the range $\{-1,0,1\}$ or $\{-1,1\}$ or something else?

Comment: @Jukka: A function $f$ with range $\{1,-1\}$ computable in some small class $\mathsf{C}$ with linear growth on the convolution with the Möbius function would be nice. I am curious most in whether the conjecture holds if we only put a polynomial-time computable restriction on $f$. But weaker results are fine, since this may be an open problem. (cont.)

Comment: Here a function is computable in $\mathsf{C}$ in the following sense: Given a binary representation of $k$ as input, there is a $\mathsf{C}$-machine (uniformly or not) such that $f(k) = 1$ if the machine accepts $k$; otherwise $f(k) = -1$. This definition corresponds to the power of the machine to simulate randomness, which is the central idea of the conjecture.

Comment: I'm not sure how much we can relax the range of $f$. I guess a constant range $\{-K,\ldots,K\}$ would be fine, and for $\{-n,\ldots,n\}$ the function $f$ exists trivially. Any ideas if $f$ has a sub-linear range?

Answer (score 5):

There have been interesting developments on this problem, however Replacing $AC^0$ with ACC(2) (Namely allowing mod 2 gates as well) is still well out-of-reach. Some progress beyond Ben Green's theorem can be found in this MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57543/walsh-fourier-transform-of-the-mobius-function as well as this one https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97261/mobius-randomness-of-the-rudin-shapiro-sequence . In addition, Jean Bourgain proved Mobius randomness for every monotone function $f$ (in terms of the binary-digit expansion).